# react-query: useQuery returns undefined and component does not rerender

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I'm playing around with `reactQuery` in a little demo app you can see in [this](https://github.com/loanburger/products-react-query) repo. The app calls [this](https://github.com/loanburger/Mongo-Api-Docker) mock API.

I'm stuck on a an issue where I'm using the `useQuery` hook to call this function in a product API [file](https://github.com/loanburger/products-react-query/blob/main/project/src/api/products.api.ts):

```
export const getAllProducts = async (): Promise<Product[]> => {
  const productEndPoint = 'http://localhost:5000/api/product';
  const { data } = await axios.get(productEndPoint);
  return data as Array<Product>;
};
```

In my [`ProductTable`](https://github.com/loanburger/products-react-query/blob/main/project/src/components/Products/ProductTable/ProductTable.tsx#L48) component I then call this function using:

```
const { data } = useQuery('products', getAllProducts);
```

I'm finding the call to the API does get made, and the data is returned. but the table in the grid is always empty.

If I debug I'm seeing the data object returned by useQuery is undefined.

The web request does successfully complete and I can see the data being returned in the network tab under requests in the browser.

I'm suspecting its the way the `getAllProducts` is structured perhaps or an async await issue but can't quite figure it out.

Can anyone suggest where IO may be going wrong please?

Comment: Sorry I misread the code. Can you prepare a codesandbox with [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter)?

Comment: Yip thanks, ill try set somethign up in the week adn ping you once done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working.  For the benefits of others ill share my learnings:

I made a few small changes starting with my api function. Changing the function to the following:

```
export const getAllProducts = async (): Promise<Product[]> => {
   const response = await axios.get(`api/product`, {
     headers: {
       Accept: 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
 });

  return response.data as Product[];
};
```

I do not de-construct the response of the `axios` call but rather take the data object from it and return is as an Product[]

Then second thing I then changed was in my `ProductTable` component. Here I told `useQuery` which type of response to expect by changing the call to :

```
const { data } = useQuery<Product[], Error>('products', getAllProducts);
```

Lastly, a rookie mistake on my part: because I was using a mock api in a docker container running on localhost and calling it using http://localhost:5000/api/product I was getting the all to well known network error:

> localhost has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...

So to get around that for the purpose of this exercise I just added a property to the packages.json file:  `"proxy":"http://localhost:5000",`

This has now successfully allowed fetching of the data as I would expect it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use like this
At first data is undefined so mapping undefined data gives you a error so we have to use isLoading and if isLoading is true we wont render or map data till then and after isLoading becomes false then we can render or return data.

```
export const getAllProducts = async (): Promise<Product[]> => {
  const productEndPoint = 'http://localhost:5000/api/product';
  const res= await axios.get(productEndPoint);
  return res.data as Array<Product>;
};

const { data:products , isLoading } = useQuery('products', getAllProducts);

if(isLoading){
return <FallBackView />
}

return (){
products.map(item => item)
}
```

Comment: Please add more details as to why this would work. Code only answers are not as obvious for other users